# mlt: format dynamictext timecode?

Tags: mlt

Is there a way to format the `#timecode#` argument in the dynamictext filter, like there is with the `#localtime#` argument?  I’d like to display only the minutes and seconds of the timecode, but entering `#timecode %M:%S#` is apparently unsupported.  I can hide the hours and frames with the `qtcrop` filter, but that feels kludgy.  Is there a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to format the #timecode# argument in the dynamictext filter, like there is with the #localtime# argument?

No.

> Is there a better way?

Maybe the count producer or the timer filters would meet your need:
https://mltframework.org/plugins/ProducerCount/

https://mltframework.org/plugins/FilterTimer/

The timer filter has a "format" option that includes "MM:SS".